# How do I use data passed back in the response from ajax jQuery?

Tags: ajax, jquery, response

I am trying to use the response from a jQuery ajax request to set the innerHTML of a div with a certain id. This is the code I am using:

```
$(".show_comments").click(function(){


var articleName = $(this).closest("article").find(".articlename").attr('id')

$.ajax({
url: "commentView.php",
data: { 'articleName': articleName },
cache: false,
dataType: "html", // so that it will auto parse it as html
success: function(response){
$(this).closest("article").find(".comments").html(response);
}
});
```

however it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all, I've tried googling around, but everything I can find says to do it the way I am doing it... I have tested in Firebug and the ajax request is giving me the exact response I want it too... But I just cant access this to set the innerHTML of the div to the response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ajax success handler there is another scope and `this` points to not what you think. So change your code to:

```
var articleName = $(this).closest("article").find(".articlename").attr('id'),
    that = this;

$.ajax({
    url: "commentView.php",
    data: { 'articleName': articleName },
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html", // so that it will auto parse it as html
    success: function(response){
        $(that).closest("article").find(".comments").html(response);
    }
});
```

What I've changed: I added `that` variable that points to `this` instance and use it in the success handler instead.

How would you debug it yourself: if you tried to output `console.log(this)` and `console.log($(this).closest("article").find(".comments"));` you would see that it returns a wrong object (in first case) and nothing in second.

Comment: Ohhhh! my bad missed the defining that XD